# error on changing view with progDailog bar

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-asynctask

I have a problem to dismiss my progbar and to change to view that I want.
My code is using asytask to do it.
the code is:

```
  private class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {
    private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(rusNewsActivite.this);
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    Dialog.setMessage("Doing something...");
        Dialog.show();

    }
```

the problems starts here:

```
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
 if(progDailog!=null)
               progDailog.dismiss();

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new LazyAdapter((Activity) mContext, nrgList, imgList);

        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

cant dismiss the proBar after the viewing items its still their and I did

```
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply then change it to

```
 if(progDailog!=null)
 progDailog.dismiss();
```

and add this line in you manifest `<activity>` tag

```
  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|navigation"
```

Comment: okn but my problem that after I get my list of items on the screen I still see the proBar. how I can dismiss it .  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 isnt helping on the code

Comment: you are showing  `Dialog`  and dismissing `progDailog` are they different ? you should dismiss dialog which you are showing.

Comment: adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); will not close your dialog it will refresh your list.